# finding center of mass of a homogenous hemisphere shell

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, physics, spherical-coordinates, spheres

### Exercise:

> Find the center of gravity of a hemispherical shell of radius $a$. (Assume the density is $1$, and place it so its base is on the $xy$-plane.

---

### Attempt:

By symmetry, the center of mass (CoM) is along the $z$-axis.

Obviously, the mass ($M$) is $2\pi a^2$

$\text{CoM}_z = \frac{1}{M}\iint_S{zdS}$

Using polar coordinates: $z = \cos \phi$ and  $dS = a^2\sin \phi d\phi d \theta$

So: $\text{CoM}_z =
\frac{1}{2\pi a^2}\int^{2\pi}_0\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0{(a \cos \phi)(a^2 \sin \phi d\phi d\theta)}
= a\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0{\cos \phi \sin \phi d\phi}
= a[\frac{1}{3}\sin^3 \phi]^\frac{\pi}{2}_0 = \frac{1}{3}a
$

---

### Answer:

$$\text{CoM} = (0, 0, \frac{1}{3}a)$$

Eyeballing it, the answer seems reasonable.

---

**Is my solution correct?**

---

Note: This is an exercise for self-study. If a mod could add the `homework-and-exercise` tag, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It should be $\frac 12a$ not $\frac 13a$

You can see that $$\int\cos\phi\sin\phi d\phi=\color{red}{\frac 12}\sin^{\color{red}{2}}\phi$$

Comment: The center of gravity cannot be half the radius. There is more mass down than up. There are at least two errors in that proof.

Comment: @RafaBudría see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388083/what-is-the-centroid-of-a-hollow-spherical-cap

Comment: Caramba. I have to revise some intuitions...

Comment: Yeah, now looking at my work, I have no idea how I ended up with that. Revising my solution now...

Answer (score 0):

Sit the hemispherical shell on the $x-y$ plane with its center through the $z$ axis. Slice it parallel with the $x-y$ axis, each slice of height $\mathrm{d}z$.

Let $\theta$ be the angle that the segment from the origin to a point on the sphere makes with the $x-y$ plane. Then $z = a \sin\theta$, and $\mathrm{d}z = a\cos\theta \mathrm{d}\theta.$

The slice at $z$ is circular and has a radius $r = a \cos\theta.$

$a\mathrm{d}\theta = \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\cos\theta}$ is the length $\mathrm{d}l$ along the edge of the sphere from $z$ to $z+\mathrm{d}z$, so the total area of a slice is $2\pi r \mathrm{d}l = 2\pi a\cos\theta\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\cos\theta} = 2\pi a\mathrm{d}z.$

This shows that all strips have the same area, and hence the same mass. So the center of mass has to be half way up, at $z = a/2$.